# Titanium Alloy put back button in a scrollableView

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy

I want to put a back button at top left on the scrollableView of iPad. If I put a button here doesn't appear on the screeen.

This is my view1.xml.

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="win1" class="contain">
        <ScrollableView id="scrollableView" showPagingControl="true">
            <View id="vista1" backgroundImage="Lois1.jpg"></View>
            <View id="vista2" backgroundImage="Lois2.jpg"></View>
            <View id="vista3" backgroundImage="Lois3.jpg"></View>
            <View id="vista4" backgroundImage="Lois4.jpg"></View>
            <View id="vista5" backgroundImage="Lois5.jpg"></View>
        </ScrollableView>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

This is my alloy.js:

```
//View 1
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    fullscreen: true});

var vista1 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundImage: 'Lois1.jpg'});
var vista2 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundImage: 'Lois2.jpg' });
var vista3 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundImage: 'Lois3.jpg' });
var vista4 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundImage: 'Lois4.jpg' });
var vista5 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundImage: 'Lois5.jpg' });

var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
  views:[vista1,vista2,vista3,vista4, vista5],
  showPagingControl:true
});

win1.add(scrollableView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not able to add button in view1.xml then you can do that in view1.js

so try to add below code in your view1.js file

```
var btnClose = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : "Close",
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE
});

$.scrollableView.add(btnClose);
```